# I need to create a log for when my application is manually stopped by force

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have an application programmed in java, and I need to save a log when it is manually stopped, either by task manager or another party.
If it can be captured by java or by some external windows application, I do not care, I just need the log that says "Hey, your application was stopped manually ..." Thanks!

PS: I have the application in netbeans, and obviously I have many logs in many methods, but I can not capture that function.

Comment: What does this question have to do with C#? Why use this question tag?

Answer (score 1):

When your application is stopped **normally**, that is when the JVM is shut down, then you can use a shutdown hook.

The code looks like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> 
      System.out.println("Hey, your application was stopped manually ...")));
```

Note that the above does not apply to abnormal JVM exists, such as when the Java process is killed. A normal exit is when either the window is closed or `ctrl+C` is used on the terminal. There's no way to register an action on to be executed on an abnormal exit.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know who turns off the application abnormally, the last alternative would be to see the windows events